# Django : cannot retrieve numbers of objects

Tags: python, django

I am working on a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (v1.11.0) project and I have this model called Album which allows every user to add albums.
I wrote the following to display the number of authenticated user, however nothing showed

```
@login_required()
def user_account(request):
    user = request.user
    user_albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    nb_albums = 0
    for i in user_albums:
        nb_albums = nb_albums + 1

    context = {
        'nb_albums': nb_albums
    }

    return render(request, 'music/user_account.html', {'user': user}, context)
```

Here is the code in the HTML page:

```
<td>{{ request.user }}</td>
<td>{{ request.user.first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ request.user.last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ request.user.email }}</td>
<td>{{ nb_albums }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code:

```
@login_required()
def user_account(request):
    user_albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    nb_albums = user_albums.count()

    return render(request, 'music/user_account.html', {'nb_albums': nb_albums})
```

and for your template:

```
<td>{{ user }}</td>
<td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ user.email }}</td>
<td>{{ nb_albums }}</td>
```